# R Markdown does not work anymore after update

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm having troubles with R Markdown. I haven't used R for a while and started using it again recently, so I needed to do some updates in R. Now, R Markdown does not work. It says that it requires some updates, but once performing the updates it gives me this error message:

```
Installing 'rmarkdown' for R Markdown...



[1/4] Installing bslib...

Installing package into 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
also installing the dependency 'htmltools'


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
           binary source needs_compilation
htmltools 0.5.1.1  0.5.3              TRUE
bslib       0.2.4  0.4.0             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/htmltools_0.5.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 242935 bytes (237 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 237 KB

package 'htmltools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpo7CXdM\downloaded_packages
installing the source package 'bslib'

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/bslib_0.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4835866 bytes (4.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.6 MB

* installing *source* package 'bslib' ...
** package 'bslib' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'htmltools' 0.5.1.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.2 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'bslib'
* removing 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/bslib'


[2/4] Installing tinytex...


The downloaded source packages are in
    'C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpo7CXdM\downloaded_packages'
Installing package into 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
also installing the dependency 'xfun'


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
        binary source needs_compilation
xfun      0.22   0.32              TRUE
tinytex   0.31   0.41             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/xfun_0.22.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 323923 bytes (316 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 316 KB

package 'xfun' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpo7CXdM\downloaded_packages
installing the source package 'tinytex'

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tinytex_0.41.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 32910 bytes (32 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 32 KB

* installing *source* package 'tinytex' ...
** package 'tinytex' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.22 is being loaded, but >= 0.29 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'tinytex'
* removing 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/tinytex'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/tinytex'


[3/4] Installing xfun...


The downloaded source packages are in
    'C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpo7CXdM\downloaded_packages'
Installing package into 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
xfun   0.22   0.32              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/xfun_0.22.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 323923 bytes (316 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 316 KB

package 'xfun' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpo7CXdM\downloaded_packages


[4/4] Installing rmarkdown...

Installing package into 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies 'htmltools', 'bslib', 'tinytex', 'xfun'

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/htmltools_0.5.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 128129 bytes (125 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 125 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/bslib_0.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4835866 bytes (4.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tinytex_0.41.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 32910 bytes (32 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 32 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xfun_0.32.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 127521 bytes (124 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 124 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rmarkdown_2.16.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3243854 bytes (3.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.1 MB

* installing *source* package 'htmltools' ...
** package 'htmltools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'htmltools'
* removing 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/htmltools'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/htmltools'
* installing *source* package 'xfun' ...
** package 'xfun' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'xfun'
* removing 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/xfun'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/xfun'
* installing *source* package 'bslib' ...
** package 'bslib' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'htmltools' 0.5.1.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.2 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'bslib'
* removing 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/bslib'
* installing *source* package 'tinytex' ...
** package 'tinytex' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.22 is being loaded, but >= 0.29 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'tinytex'
* removing 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/tinytex'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/tinytex'
ERROR: dependency 'bslib' is not available for package 'rmarkdown'
* removing 'C:/Users/nicol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rmarkdown'

The downloaded source packages are in
    'C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpo7CXdM\downloaded_packages'


<U+2714> Package 'rmarkdown' successfully installed.
Warning messages:
1: In utils::install.packages("bslib", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package 'bslib' had non-zero exit status
2: In utils::install.packages("tinytex", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package 'tinytex' had non-zero exit status
3: In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package 'htmltools' had non-zero exit status
4: In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package 'xfun' had non-zero exit status
5: In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package 'bslib' had non-zero exit status
6: In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package 'tinytex' had non-zero exit status
7: In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  installation of package 'rmarkdown' had non-zero exit status
```

Does anyone know what I should do to make it work again?

Best regards
Nicolas

Comment: not sure I can help debug this, but you might want to check out quarto which will give you the same functionality and maybe fewer headaches

Comment: You are trying to install source packages on Windows.  That needs a current version of Rtools, available from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ .  Alternatively, install the binary versions.

Comment: @pluke:  Quarto won't give you fewer headaches.  It has some real advantages over RMarkdown, but maturity isn't one of them.

Comment: @user2554330: Thank you! That helped. It also turned out that I had an old R version.